# ASP.Net Core MVC authentication with Microsoft

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-8.0

I am using the ASP.Net Core MVC application in .Net 8. I have configured Microsoft login, but when I log in it is automatically logged in by using the previously logged-in account. Instead, I want to enable the option to pick an account before login. How to do this?

Please find my configuration given below.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddCookie().AddMicrosoftAccount(MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.ClientId = builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftKeys:ClientId").Value;
    options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftKeys:ClientSecret").Value;
});
```

I want to show like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fOXW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the event to enforce the user to select account before logining.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
{
    microsoftOptions.ClientId = builder.Configuration["MicrosoftKeys:ClientId"];
    microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["MicrosoftKeys:ClientSecret"];

    microsoftOptions.Events = new OAuthEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint = context =>
        {
            // Force the user to select an account on the Microsoft login page
            context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri + "&prompt=select_account");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});
```

[image]